# Is this case of a generalised partition equivalent to Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $k=m+\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j$ such that $a,m,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_1$ or $a_{m+1}\geq 0$ with all other $a\geq1$. Note that we assume natural numbers start from $0$ and we have the restriction that $\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j\geq m-1$. Why do there exist $F_{k+2}$ solution sets for values of $m$ and $a_\zeta$, $\forall1\leq\zeta\leq m$? How would this be proven?

For example, when $k=4$, we have $8$ solution sets,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{m,A\}&=\{0,\{4\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{3,0\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{0,3\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{1,2\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{2,1\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{0,1,1\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{1,1,0\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{0,2,0\}\},\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $A=\bigcup^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j$. Note that $\{2,\{1,0,1\}\}$ is invalid since only the first or final $a$'s may be $0$. Also, $\{3,\{0,1,0\}\}$ is invalid since $\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j\geq m-1$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**: Let $b_j=a_j-1$ for $1<j<m+1$ and $b_j=a_j$ when $j=1$ or $j=m+1$:
$$k=2m-1+\sum _{j=1}^{m+1}b_j.$$
Hence, for fixed $m$, there exist
$$\binom{k-2m+1+m+1-1}{m+1-1}=\binom{k-m+1}{m},$$
solutions for $k-2m+1=b_1+\cdots +b_{m+1}$. Summing over $m$ yields
$$F_{k+2}=\sum _{m=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1-m}{m}.$$

Comment: Your last equation is a well-known result, that the Fibonacci numbers appear when summing in Pascal's triangle "along a diagonal". Consider e.g. http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibmaths.html#section9.1

Comment: @user44191 Thank you very much! Yes, I was too caught up in notation to realise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without mistake on my behalf, a proof can be given as follows:

Denote the set of all solutions (for a given value of $k$)
by
$\mathcal F_k$. Every element of $\mathcal F_k$ ending
with a last coefficient $\geq 1$ corresponds to an element
of $\mathcal F_{k-1}$ after decreasing its last element
(of the corresponding sequence $(a_1,\ldots)$) by $1$.
Elements of $\mathcal F_k$ ending with a last coefficient $0$
correspond similarly to elements of $\mathcal F_{k-2}$:
Remove the last coefficient and decrease the (originally second-last)
remaining last coefficient by $1$. This proves the result by
induction after checking the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like your method as it seems more elegant than mine.